# python: numpy and np.where. Index

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, indexing

I have the `list=[12,45,7,15,9]` and I sorted it in a descending order.

So now I have `[45,15,12,9,7]`
 Now I have to take the first 3 elements, and I have to find the indices of the first list where are `(45,15,12)`.
I used `np.where`, but this is the error:

```
__main__:1: DeprecationWarning: elementwise == comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
```

Comment: You received warning not error.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't manage to give me the indices, infact it gives me an empty array.

Comment: You should post your code so we can see what you're doing. The warning may only be a warning but it suggests you're not calling `where` in a supported manner.

Comment: I think that the problem is that the elements are 3, infact with one element it manage to give me an answer

Comment: My code is:      
        copy=grad_u(kkk,alfa,e,Y).astype(int)
        a=(np.array(sorted(grad_u(kkk,alfa,e,Y)).astype(int))
        s1=a[0:q1]
        s2=np.where(copy==s1)

Comment: I don't think that's your actual code: it's not valid (The `(` before `np.array` has no matching `)`.) I don't know numpy, and I think it's going to be hard to help out without knowing what your input variables are. I suggest you edit your question to provide a [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as this will aid those who may be able to help.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code, preferably a minimal example that will let someone reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you are trying to do something like np.where(x,y,z) when it's better to search the indices individually.  Also, it helps to make sure that your list is typed as a numpy array before you try to use np.where on it.

```
import numpy as np

alist=[12,45,7,15,9] 
alist=np.array(alist)

anewlist=[45,15,12,9,7]
anewlist=np.array(anewlist)
x=anewlist[0]
y=anewlist[1]
z=anewlist[2]
print(np.where(alist == x))
print(np.where(alist == y))
print(np.where(alist == z))

>>>(array([1], dtype=int64),)
   (array([3], dtype=int64),)
   (array([0], dtype=int64),)
```

Comment: I can't call x,y,z etc because I can't fix the number of elements. Infact I have to change the number of the taken elements.

Comment: You don't have to.  I just did that to make it easier to follow.  `np.where(alist == anewlist[0])` will work just as well as  `np.where(alist == x)`

Comment: Yep, just tested it.  No difference.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for what you are trying to do can be following:

```
list = np.array([12,45,7,15,9])
ind = list.argsort()[-3:][::-1]
```

output :

> array([1, 3, 0], dtype=int64)

it will give you the indeces of the three elemnts.